# Installing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have installed beautifulsoup for Python, but it gives me this error when I import the library:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Playroom/WebScraper_01.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: How did you install it? did you use pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you get the ImportError “No module named HTMLParser”, your problem is that you’re running the Python 2 version of the code under Python 3.
- If you get the ImportError “No module named html.parser”, your problem is that you’re running the Python 3 version of the code under Python 2.

See: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation